# Incorrect SLComposeViewControllerResult while sharing on facebook using iOS SocialFramework

Tags: ios, ios9, slcomposeviewcontroller, ios9.1

I am using Social framework for sharing from my iOS application and testing my iOS application on iOS9. When I click on share button it opens native facebook application ViewController as shown in following image.

[image]

The problem is that irrespective of user clicks post or hit back button it still return SLComposeViewControllerResultDone result. Here is my completion handler for SLComposeViewController. Here is code:

```
NSLog(@"%@Controller presenting",socialMediaSLType);//socialMediaSLType is SLServiceTypeFacebook
        SLComposeViewController *controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:socialMediaSLType];
        [controllerSLC setInitialText:@""];
        [controllerSLC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
        [controllerSLC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASEURL,image]]];
        [controllerSLC setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            switch (result) {
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Post Canceled");
                    break;
                case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    NSLog(@"Post Done");
                    break;
            }
        }];
        [self presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:nil];
```